# How to convert an Android Studio project to an Appcelerator Titanium Module

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, appcelerator

Hy guys!
So, i have this tutorial, and it raised some questions.

[Titanium-AndroidStudio](https://github.com/AppWerft/Titanium-AndroidStudio)

In short, it shows how to open the Appcelerator Libraries on Android Studio and use it to develop the Modules.

What I need, is sort of the other way around.

I have an AndroidStudio Project which I need to "convert" to an Appcelerator Titanium Module. The Java code is not a problem, since Java is Java. But there are a lot of things to consider. The Android Studio uses it's own screen/buttons/views implementation, and the Appcelerator Module is pure java made in Eclipse, and the screen, views, buttons, etc, are created using Javascript inside the Titanium framework.

I am going to give an exemple.

This is a snipet from Android Studio.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestPermissions();
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tire_scan);

    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (audioManager != null) { 
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
    }

    btnAccept = findViewById(R.id.btnAccept);
    mOpenCvCameraView = findViewById(R.id.java_camera_View);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
}
```

So, we have some Java code that do some stuff, and we also have the behavior of the App itself related to the Java code, like the camera view and the button.

How to remove the "visual" code from this snippet, and relate it to the Appcelerator Javascript code.

This button, for example, would have to be built inside appcelerator, like this:

```
var VBtn = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: 'CameraButton',
    bottom: 50,
});
```

I don't know if I am clear on this but, I hope you understand me.

Basically, how to migrate a project from Android Studio to an Appcelerator Module and use it inside Titanium itself.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

This is what I have so far.

The ViewProxy and the View classes.

```
@Kroll.proxy(creatableInModule = ItiremoduleModule.class)
public class ItireViewProxy extends TiViewProxy 
{
public ItireViewProxy() 
{
    super();
}

PortraitCameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
AppCompatActivity appCom;

protected class ItireView extends TiUIView
{
    public ItireView(TiViewProxy proxy) {
        super(proxy);

        String packageName = proxy.getActivity().getPackageName();
        Resources resources = proxy.getActivity().getResources();
        View viewWrapper;

        int java_camera_View = resources.getIdentifier("java_camera_View", "id", packageName);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(proxy.getActivity());
        viewWrapper = inflater.inflate(java_camera_View, null);

        setNativeView(viewWrapper);
    }
}

@Override
public TiUIView createView(Activity activity) {
    TiUIView view = new ItireView(this);
    view.getLayoutParams().autoFillsHeight = true;
    view.getLayoutParams().autoFillsWidth = true;
    return view;
}

@Kroll.method
public void setView() {
    // must use this method to set the view on Appcelerator, right?
    }

}
```

The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:itiremodule="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.itire.budini"
xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.itire.budini"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.itire.budini.ItireViewProxy">

<com.example.etech.opencvtest320.PortraitCameraView
    android:id="@+id/java_camera_View"
    android:layout_width="379dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    opencv:camera_id="any"
    opencv:show_fps="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAccept"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="375dp"
    android:layout_height="76dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:onClick="scanAgain"
    android:text="Scanning iTread..."
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#1F2025"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is a great tutorial it is a bit out-dated. Beginning with Titanium 9.0.0 it is easier to use Android Studio. Have a look at: https://dev.to/miga/using-android-studio-to-develop-titanium-modules-2jc4 on how to get it up and running.

The other part is not true either. You can use native UI elements in modules (or even in Hyperloop):

- here I use a native Layout XML in Hyperloop: https://github.com/m1ga/hyperloop.collapsingToolbarLayout
- and in this module I use an XML layout which I fill inside the module: [the XML layout](https://github.com/m1ga/ti.vonage/blob/master/android/platform/android/res/layout/layout_main.xml) - [The connection part](https://github.com/m1ga/ti.vonage/blob/master/android/src/ti/vonage/VonageViewProxy.java#L72)

This will even create a custom View you can use in your controller later like this `<VonageView module="ti.vonage" id="vonage"/>`

Keep in mind: unlike other Frameworks Titanium uses native UI elements and only JS for the connection/code layer between your UI and the logic.

keepScreenOn is already inside the SDK: 
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-keepScreenOn

If other parts are missing like `setStreamVolume` you could even add them in the SDK (e.g. here [TiSound](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/android/modules/media/src/java/ti/modules/titanium/media/TiSound.java)) since it is open source and might be useful for other people too.

Comment: Hey @miga, thanks for the answer. Does it works with a Classical Titanium project? Because the company where I work does not use Alloy, only Classical projects.

Comment: of course. All Alloy projects are compiled down to classic. If you don't use it (I would recommend doing it :) ) you just have to use `createVonageView()` or how you call your module. So you wlil be fine with Classic too

Comment: So, let me see if I get it. First of all I need to have a xml file on the following directory: myModule/android/platform/android/res/layout/myXMLFile.xml .  Secondly, I need to specify it like this: myVar = resources.getIdentifier("resourceName", "resource", packName) . Is that it?

Comment: it all depends on your native app. Normally a module is just a module and not the whole app e.g. a videoplayer :) Have a look at https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Android+Module+Architecture for the structure. Another thing you could do is to create an AAR file from the native app and start it in Titanium. A basic how-to for Unity can be found here: https://github.com/m1ga/from_zero_to_app/blob/master/unity3d_in_titanium.md should work for native apps too (haven't done that yet)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help! How do call your createView method? I'm trying to use it on the onAppCreate method, so the view can be rendered as the app initializes, but I always get the Error invoking: com.myApp.MyMethodModuleClass.onAppCreate()

Comment: `onAppCreate()` is called automatically when you run your app. And `createView()` is called when you (or alloy) creates the view. In my case when I use `<VonageView>`. In this module I set the `image` property `<SvgView image=""/>` (https://github.com/m1ga/ti.svg/blob/master/android/src/ti/svg/SvgViewProxy.java#L89) and use it inside  `createView()` (https://github.com/m1ga/ti.svg/blob/master/android/src/ti/svg/SvgViewProxy.java#L76) because otherwise the view is not there yet. So you have you have to add the view in Titanium first before you can render into it. Hope that helps :)

Comment: So, you call setImage, which sets it, then it calls handleCreationDict, which calls the createView? Is that it? In my case, I need to render a cameraView, which cannot be the Ti.Media.showCamera, because that native camera doesn't do what I need. I Will update my question with what I have so far.

Comment: inside Titanium you would use your module like this `var iv = require("ItireView").createItireView(); win.add(iv);` That will call the `createView` function. The `setView()` method can be used with `iv.setView()`.  If that doesn't solve it please start with a smaller example and some log output to see when each of the functions is called. Also check other modules and the linked docu. I don't want to write your whole module :-) E.g. I would create the Button in Titanium. Easier to add eventListeners/place it without compiling the module all the time and then I would call methods from the module

Comment: the ti.vonage example has most of the code you'll need: it has a native xml view, some methods and it will be added in titanium. It even displays two camera streams (which are created by the external library)

Comment: Thank you very, very much for your support. I will see what I can do, and will update you about the results!

Comment: No matter what I do, the `int java_camera_View = resources.getIdentifier("java_camera_View", "id", packageName);` always return 0, therefore giving error in the module when I try to run it on Titanium.... I put the xml file just like it is on Vonage View `android \ platform \ android \ res \ layout` , and tried to move it from other folders, such as `android \ platform \ android \ res \ xml`

Comment: https://github.com/m1ga/test_layout just chagned the custom view in the XML into a normal RelativeLayout. When you run the module it will show the layout from the XML and it sets the color in code.

Comment: btw: feel free to join our slack at: tislack.org/ a bit better to chat ;-)

Comment: After some struggle, I finally made it work thanks to your support. Now I am facing other erros within my app, but it has to do with the OpenCV Android Library, so, the main question here is answered. Thanks a lot!